# Angular, 2 subjects, combineLatest not working

Tags: angular, rxjs

```
  $query: Subject<string> = new Subject();
  $order: Subject<string> = new Subject();

  constructor() {
    combineLatest([this.$query, this.$order]).pipe(
      debounceTime(300),
      startWith([null, 'Oldest'])
    ).subscribe(([query, order]) => {
      console.log('query', query);
      console.log('order', order);
    });  
  }
```

Logs showed only once and after I try to call `$query.next('sthg')`, it's not working.

Does anybody have any idea why? I want to log the values if the `$query` or the `$order` gets a new value. Is combine latest not working with subjects?

Answer (score 4):

All source Observables need to emit at least once so you could use this instead:

```
combineLatest([
  this.$query.pipe(startWith(null)),
  this.$order.pipe(startWith("Oldest")),
]).pipe(
  debounceTime(300),
)
.subscribe(...);
```

This way you'll get the first emision that you expect and then it should emit on every change.

Answer (score 0):

In order for this to work, both observables must emit at least one value, according to [the documentation](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/combinelatest).
You can try something like this:

```
  combineLatest([this.$query, this.$order.pipe(startWith("Oldest")]).pipe(
    debounceTime(300),
  ).subscribe(([query, order]) => {
    console.log('query', query);
    console.log('order', order);
  });
```

Then when you will call `$query.next('sthg')` you should see your console logs.

Answer (score 0):

Quated from [combineLatest (learnrxjs.io)](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/combinelatest)

Be aware that combineLatest **will not emit an initial value until each observable emits at least one value**. This is the same behavior as withLatestFrom and can be a gotcha as there will be no output and no error but one (or more) of your inner observables is likely not functioning as intended, or a subscription is late.

Personally i use `BehaviorSubject` as sources and add `filter` pipe to escape unwanted combinaiton:

```
combineLatest([this.obs1$, this.obs2$, this.obs3$])
    .pipe(
      filter((result) => {
        let valueObs1 = result[0];
        let valueObs2 = result[1];
        let valueObs3 = result[2];

        if (logic tgo escape) 
             return false;

        return true;
      })
    )
    .subscribe(
      (result) => console.log(result),
      (error) => console.log(error)
    );
```